# Custom Mapping Dapper.NET

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I could done like this but I think there should be a way to do this better;

```
    Resource.ResourceIncrease resource = new Resource.ResourceIncrease();

    using (IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection())
    {
        dynamic reader = connection.Query<dynamic>("UserResourceGet", new { UserId = UserId }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
        resource.Wood.value = reader.Wood;
        resource.Wood.increase = reader.WoodIncome;

        resource.Food.value = reader.Food;
        resource.Food.increase = reader.FoodIncome;

        resource.Stone.value = reader.Stone;
        resource.Stone.increase = reader.StoneIncome;

        resource.Gold.value = reader.Gold;
        resource.Gold.increase = reader.GoldIncome;
    }
    return resource;
```

SQL SP >

```
SELECT  Wood, Food, Stone, Gold, WoodIncome, FoodIncome, StoneIncome, GoldIncome
FROM Resources WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

Class >

```
public class Resource
{
    public int Wood { get; set; }
    public int Food { get; set; }
    public int Stone { get; set; }
    public int Gold { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceIncrease
{
    public Increase Wood{ get; set; }
    public Increase Food { get; set; }
    public Increase Stone { get; set; }
    public Increase Gold { get; set; }

    public ResourceIncrease()
    {
        this.Wood = new Increase();
        this.Food = new Increase();
        this.Stone = new Increase();
        this.Gold = new Increase();
    }
}

public class Increase
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public int increase { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class that match the return of the SP, and then would use AutoMapper (http://automapper.org/) to map that class to the ResourceIncrease class.

Check this
http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2012/01/03/mapping-and-auto-mapping-objects.aspx